# How does Firebases anonymous authentication generate a UID?

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase

Is this based on the clients machine or browser or something else?

For example if I logged in anonymously using Chrome, would the same UID be used in Firefox on the same machine?

Answer (score 6):

From the [Firebase documentation on anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth):

> Each time you login a user anonymously, a new, unique user ID will be generated, and your Firebase reference will be authenticated using these new credentials.

So each of the browsers (in your example) becomes a different user.

Comment: Okay thanks, I was trying to understand how Firebase is able to detect that the same anonymous user is visiting again. From my own testing it appears that loging the user in on Chrome and then closing the browser window and opening it again, Firebase is able to remember that it's the same user. But firefox is treated as a new user so it must be based on the browser client rather than the machine. This wasn't clear to me in the Firebase docs.

Comment: The fact that you become the same uid in the same browser is indeed not explicitly documented. Note that this also only is the case until you call `unauth`. Once you call `unauth`, your token is list and you will get new uid.

Comment: Okay, so does this mean that something unique in a browser client is matched to an anonymous unique user ID record in Firebase? Until that record is destroyed either by calling unauth or it expiring over time depending on how long you've configured the session. Or is some kind of session token stored on the client maybe?

Comment: FWIW, I have noticed that on iOS even between reinstalls of the app, the anon identifier is somehow persisting. Are they using the keychain or something?

Comment: And updated link to docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth